# Angular2 how to get array data from .toPromise()

Tags: angular, angular2-services

This is the http function

```
test(siteId: string, eqId: string, viewId: number): Promise<IEquipmentImage[]> {
      const getOptions = {
        params: {
          SiteID: siteId,
          EquipmentID: eqId,
          ViewID: viewId.toString()
        }
      };

 return <IEquipmentImage[]>await this.http.get(this.equipmentViewConfig.EquipmentImageUrl, getOptions)
      .toPromise();
    }
```

It will return as a promise but I checked in console it return something like this:

[image]

How can I get the array value ONLY (_zone_symbol_value) ? instead of all those things

Answer (score 1):

If you are using promise , you can use callback function **.then()**  to get the value and **.catch()** for handling error .

If you need reactive programming style you can use observables. By using **.map()**, **.subscribe()** , you can get the value on the top of observables

In your code add a callback function on the top of promise

```
    <IEquipmentImage[]>await this.http.get(this.equipmentViewConfig.EquipmentImageUrl, getOptions)
          .toPromise().then(function(response){
//here you will get the value in response object
});
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
<IEquipmentImage[]>await this.http.get(this.equipmentViewConfig.EquipmentImageUrl, getOptions)
          .toPromise().then(function(response){
//here you will get the value in response object
});
```

to

```
<IEquipmentImage[]>await this.http.get(this.equipmentViewConfig.EquipmentImageUrl, getOptions).map((res: Response) => res.json())
          .toPromise().then(function(response){
//here you will get the value in response object
});
```